# Import certificate_transparency in Python

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I have an error on an application that ran before well:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
```

The version of cryptography library is 2.2.2 and I made sue that the file `certificate_transparency.py` exists in the required folder. What could be the root of the above problem?

```
pip 10.0.1 from /home/serj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, something wrong with cryptography. Try

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cryptography
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. But it requires changes to the source code.

1. Add path of the certificate_transparency file:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509'))
```

2. Change the code in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py`

Then replace this (old line):
`from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency`

with this (new line):
`import certificate_transparency`